# Can Cassandra DB or Mongo DB be used for configuring multiple DBs?

Tags: database, mongodb, cassandra, redis, redis-cluster

The older version of REdis supported multiple DBs, but since the latest version does not support multiple DBs, I would like to know if Cassandra or Mongo can be used ?

I would require multiple DBs cause I use the same Redis Instance to support different application databases

Answer (score 1):

Redis and Cassandra are very different beasts - and used for different goals. Where Redis is mostly in-mem storage (like caches), cassandra is built to store your data on-disc.

You could define multiple key-spaces and multiple tables (within the key-spaces) to emulate the 'multiple DBs' that redis offers. but again, I think you'd probably be using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: How can I make use of latest version of Redis cluster to emulate the multiple DBs just like the previous version of redis?